# Set grid to 75% of parent grid

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

I don't know how to do this in `WPF`. Here is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" Width="500">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.Background >
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Public\Images\chat_green-textarea.png"/>
                </Grid.Background>

                <TextBlock Padding="5" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" TextWrapping="Wrap">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</TextBlock>                                    
            </Grid>

            <Grid Grid.Row ="1">
                <Image Source="Public\Images\chat_green-textarea-tail.png" Height="20" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,-4,0,0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I am displaying a `Text` in a `Grid`, but I want its max width to be set equals to the 75% of its parent grid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in it another grid with two columns with column definitions

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <columndefinition Width="3*"/>
            <columndefintiion Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            ... <snip> ...
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Put your target grid in the first column of the wrapper grid and now it
will have 75% width of it's parent.

Comment: I realized the true meaning of the * sign. Haha. Thanks!